# Could not find “store” in either the context or props React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm trying to integrate Redux in my React Native app. I am getting the error "Could not find “store” in either the context or props"

My code is as follows:

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { reducer } from './containers/intro/introRedux'

const store = createStore(reducer);

import App from './App'

const AppWithStore = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App  />
    </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => AppWithStore)
```

App.js

```
//Components & Dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Picker, TouchableOpacity, Image, AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { actionCreators } from './containers/intro/introRedux'


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  todos: state.todos,
})

//Styles
var introStyle = require('./containers/intro/styles');

class App extends Component {
  profile = {
    gender: "Female",
    heightUnit: "cm",
    weightUnit: "kg"
  }

  saveProfile() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.profile));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper ref={(component) => { this.swiper = component; }} dotColor='#2A2D2E' activeDotColor='#FFF' showsButtons={false} loop={false}>
        <View style={introStyle.slide1}>
          <Image source={require('./images/logo.png')} />
          <Text style={introStyle.header}>Build Muscle, Burn Fat &amp; Get Stronger</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={introStyle.nextButton} onPress={() => this.swiper.scrollBy(1)}>
            <Text style={introStyle.nextButtonText}>Next</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={introStyle.slide2}>
          <View style={introStyle.wrapper}>
            <Text style={introStyle.header}>Let's setup your profile</Text>
            <Text style={introStyle.subHeader}>Tell us a little about yourself first</Text>

            <Picker
              selectedValue={this.profile.gender}
              mode='dropdown'
              style={[introStyle.dropdown, introStyle.genderDropdown]}>
              <Picker.Item label="Male" value="Male" />
              <Picker.Item label="Female" value="Female" />
            </Picker>

            <TextInput
              style={introStyle.textInput}
              underlineColorAndroid='#FFF'
              placeholder='Age'
              keyboardType='numeric'
              maxLength={2}
              value={this.profile && this.profile.age}
            />

            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
              <TextInput
                style={introStyle.textInput}
                underlineColorAndroid='#FFF'
                placeholder='Height'
                keyboardType='numeric'
                maxLength={3}
                value={this.profile && this.profile.height}
              />
              <Picker
                mode='dropdown'
                style={introStyle.dropdown}
                selectedValue={this.profile.heightUnit}
              >
                <Picker.Item label="cm" value="cm" />
                <Picker.Item label="inch" value="inch" />
              </Picker>
            </View>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
              <TextInput
                style={introStyle.textInput}
                underlineColorAndroid='#FFF'
                placeholder='Weight'
                keyboardType='numeric'
                maxLength={3}
                value={this.profile && this.profile.weight}
              />
              <Picker
                mode='dropdown'
                style={introStyle.dropdown}
                selectedValue={this.profile.weightUnit}
              >
                <Picker.Item label="kg" value="kg" />
                <Picker.Item label="lb" value="lb" />
              </Picker>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={introStyle.nextButton} onPress={() => this.saveProfile()}>
              <Text style={[introStyle.nextButtonText, { textAlign: 'center' }]}>Let's go!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

introRedux.js

```
const initialState = {
    todos: ['Click to remove', 'Learn React Native', 'Write Code', 'Ship App'],
}

export const actionCreators = {
    UPDATE_GENDER: 'UPDATE_GENDER',
};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const {profile} = state
    const {type, payload} = action

    switch (type) {
        case types.ADD: {
          return {
            ...state,
            todos: [payload, ...todos],
          }
        }
        case types.REMOVE: {
          return {
            ...state,
            todos: todos.filter((todo, i) => i !== payload),
          }
        }
    }

    return state
}
```

Why can't the app find the store from the provider? I'm at a loss.

**Edit: passing the store directly works:**

```
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native'

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { reducer } from './containers/intro/introRedux'

const store = createStore(reducer)

// Import the App container component
import App from './App'

// Pass the store into the app container
const AppWithStore = () => <App store={store} />

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => AppWithStore)
```

"App" doesn't use connect to export the component if I pass the store directly

Comment: Are there more details about the error? I can't spot anything particularly wrong.

Comment: One thing you could do is simply replace App inside the Provider with a simpler component that just displays a Hello World. If that works, then the problem is inside App.

Comment: @nbkhope if I pass the store directly to the app app works fine, see my update, any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters, but could you try changing the first argument to `AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppWithStoreHere', () => AppWithStore)`

Comment: "Passing store directly" as you said will work because you are passing a prop called store to the component. That is expected. Somehow your Provider is not injecting the "store" prop into its children components. That seems to be the issue here.

Comment: Still getting the same error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)" with the updated line for AppRegistry :/

Comment: Ohh, there is your problem! Footer!

Comment: crap, no, I copied and pasted the error from online, can't copy from my phone (using Expo), it's Connect(App)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
const AppWithStore = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App  />
    </Provider>
)
```

with a class component:

```
class AppWithStore extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Functional components do not keep state. I think `AppRegistry.registerComponent` needs you to use a class component.

**Edit2**

```
{
  "name": "vtapered",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.3.1",
    "jest-expo": "~20.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^20.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.10",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, that seems a very odd issue. Could you post the package versions you're using for react, react-redux, etc?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking at, give me a few, I will update the post with package versions

Comment: @Hirvesh according to the docs, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html, `AppRegistry` "only works in projects made with react-native init or in those made with Create React Native App which have since ejected." You mentioned Expo, so did you create the app using create-react-native-app? That might be a problem?

Comment: I did create with  create-react-native-app, when I do npm start, it gives instructions to run on expo

Comment: Added package.json file as well

Comment: I'm trying to update all packages to the latest versions

Comment: The code is near identical to what's on react native express here: (without the redux persist part): http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/redux_persist

Comment: Yeah, but you have to understand the AppRegistry is abstracted when you do `create-react-native-app`. You only get an index with the actual initial component, right? You don't see AppRegistry in the app generated by create-react-native-app, do you? Read my previous comment.

Comment: I only managed to test it now, thanks a bunch! It worked. I need to run the app without Expo, I ejected from CRNA and all is fine now :)